# how to get the output of DDL commands Python cx_oracle

Tags: python, ddl, cx-oracle

I am currently working with cx_oracle

Here with SELECT statements I am able to use the fetchall() function to get rows.

But how to get the outputs for queries that fall under Data Definition Language (DDL) category.

For example, after executing a GRANT statement with cursor.execute(), the expected output assuming the query is valid would be,

"GRANT executed successfully"

But how do I get this with cx_oracle, Python.

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you have print it yourself, which is what SQL*Plus does.

DDL statements are statements not queries because they do not return data.  They return a success or error condition to the tool that executed them, which can then print any message.  In your case the tool is cx_Oracle.  There isn't a way to get the type (GRANT, CREATE etc) of the statement automatically in cx_Oracle.  Your application can either print a generic message like 'statement executed successfully', or you can extract the first keyword(s) from the SQL statement so you can print a message like SQL*Plus does.

Comment: Thanks, this is all the understanding I needed. I have explored a lot more using the above answer as reference.
Currently attempting an implementation with subprocess and sqlplus

Comment: Thanks, i have been able to accomplish  the above using subprocess and sqlplus.

Comment: I would suggest you do not do that.  Just run the statements in cx_Oracle which has better flow control than SQL\*Plus.  Also invoking SQL\*Plus requires entering the password somehow which could be a security risk.  And it is extra overhead.